# ASUS Xonar Essence STX II on Xubuntu 15.04?

Tags: drivers, sound, xubuntu, 15.04

I'm currently running Xubuntu 15.04 using an ASUS Essence STX II sound card which is recognized and is working, but I'd like to know if there are any programs available that allow me to set up and configure the sound card similar to how I can in windows and its 'ASUS Essence STX II Audio Center'.  Settings like:

[image]

[image]

I've read that people have had success setting up the previous edition of this card (Essence STX) on earlier versions of Ubuntu and have been able to tweak all the settings and the sounds is just as good if not better than in windows. ALSA and the virtuoso driver?

What programs and/or drivers do I need in order to be able to take full advantage of this card? I'm pretty new to Linux and Ubuntu so the more details the better.

Comment: You may be able to run the programs themselves in wine, but if they work out of the box I wouldn't touch them.

Comment: But aren't there native applications I can use to tweak/use for equalizer settings, etc?

Comment: For EQ, I'm not sure.  There may be some in the default system sound settings

Answer (score 1):

You can set most important settings by installing alsamixer and then run the console version of it.

It allows you to change headphone impedence and dac filter rolloff

For the tonal settings I'm too looking for some solution.